# setImageData fails in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios

I am using setImageData to delete a photo in the following way :

```
[asset setImageData:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
{
    // Do something
}];
```

This code was working perfectly fine in iOS 8.2 and earlier versions.

But, in 8.3 it gives the error :

> @"Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3311 \"User denied access\" UserInfo=0x175061ac0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The user has denied the application access to their media., NSLocalizedDescription=User denied access, NSUnderlyingError=0x17025d700 \"The operation couldn’t be completed. (ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain error -3311.)\”}"

I tried replacing the image data and metadata fields with some valid image data instead of “nil”. Still it gives the same error!!

Is this some bug in iOS 8.3? Is there any workaround?

Thanks in anticipation.

Another important information :

[PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus] returns  "PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized". 
[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] also returns "ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized".

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the setImageData method was never intended to be used as a method for deleting assets. It is possible that on iOS 8.3 Apple patched things up so this no longer works.

I recommend that you look into using the Photos framework which includes a dedicated method for deleting assets.
Here's an example:

```
-(void)deleteAssetWithURL:(NSString*)assetURLString
{
    NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:assetURLString];
    if (assetURL == nil)
    {
        return;
    }

    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[assetURL] options:nil];
    if (result.count > 0)
    {
        PHAsset *phAsset = result.firstObject;
        if ((phAsset != nil) && ([phAsset canPerformEditOperation:PHAssetEditOperationDelete]))
        {
            [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^
            {
                [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[phAsset]];
            }
                                              completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
             {
                 if ((!success) && (error != nil))
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error deleting asset: %@", [error description]);
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
}
```

When using the Photos framework, don't forget to link `Photos.framework` in your target and also import the header in your source file: `#import <Photos/Photos.h>`

Comment: Awesome answer. Should also mention that you need to #import <Photos/Photos.h>

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and haven't been able to resolve it either. I think its a bug in 8.3 with the AssetsLibrary, and would suggest you submit a bug report to Apple as I have:

[Can't edit photo metadata using AssetsLibrary in iOS 8.3 (worked in 8.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105468/cant-edit-photo-metadata-using-assetslibrary-in-ios-8-3-worked-in-8-2)

Answer (score -1):

> The user has denied the application access to their media

This explains why you have the error. As far as the system is concerned you don't have access to the photo library.

You need to look at checking the authorization status and requesting if needed as show in the [Apple Doc's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHPhotoLibrary/authorizationStatus)

You need something like:

```
if([PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus] != PHAuthorizationStatus.PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){  
   [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status)
   {
      if (status != PHAuthorizationStatus.PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
      {
        //Fail
      }
      else
      {
        //SetImageData
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I checked [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus] in my code. It gives : "PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized".   [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] also gives "ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized". Please note that, the same code, without a single change works perfectly fine in 8.2!! So, it is something related to the changes from 8.2 to 8.3!!!

Comment: Authorisation looks at the same settings property.

Have you checked that the asset is "editable"

Whilst I can see no reason why this wouldn't work on 8.3 but works on 8.2. It should be pointed out that AssetLibrary is most likely going to be deprecated in future versions, over the PhotoKit Framework

Comment: Yes. I have put a check for "editable" property before I try deleting the asset.